# angular 2 constructor inside service working another functions inside services not working

Tags: angular, typescript, constructor, angular-services

**my code**

component.ts page:

```
import {Component, OnInit, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { UserService } from "../services/user.service";
import {Router, ActivatedRoute, Params  } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
       selector: 'app-all-users',
       templateUrl: './all-users.component.html',
       styleUrls: ['./all-users.component.css'],
       providers: [ UserService ]
 })

export class AllUsersComponent{
   users; usersnew; limit; limitnew;  

constructor(public userService: UserService, public router: Router,  public route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.limit = "0";
  this.limitnew = "0";
  this.userService.getTestUsers(this.limit).subscribe(  users => this.users = users);
}
LoadMore(){  
  this.limit = "12";
  this.limitnew = +this.limitnew + +this.limit;
  this.userService.getTestUsers(this.limitnew).subscribe(  usersnew => this.usersnew = usersnew);
  this.users = [...this.users , ...this.usersnew];
  console.log(this.users);
  }
}
```

html page:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 *ngFor="let user of users ;let i = index ">
   <img *ngIf="user.image == ''"  src="http://localhost/assets/images/user.png"  class="user_img">
  </div>
</div>
<button (click)="LoadMore()"> Load More </button>
```

userService page:

```
import { Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core'; import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'; import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Injectable()
export class UserService{
  constructor(private http: Http) { this.http = http; }

 getTestUsers(limitid): Observable<any> {        
     return this.http.get("http://localhost/AdminApp/api/get_all_user.php?id="+ limitid).map(res => res.json());
  }
 }
```

my question is component.ts page **constructor**  inside **userSerice** is working.

but **LoadMore** function inside **userService** not working

Comment: Please give a [mcve] - what exactly does *"not working"* mean?

Comment: print log this.usersnew inside the subscribe in loadMore Method. if you get the value inside the subscribe method your code is correct

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: console.log of subscribe inside , i get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
export class AllUsersComponent {
    users: Array<any> = [];
    usersnew: Array<any> = [];
    limit; limitnew;

    constructor(public userService: UserService, public router: Router, public route: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.limit = "0";
        this.limitnew = "0";
        this.userService.getTestUsers(this.limit).subscribe(users => this.users = users);
    }

    LoadMore() {
        this.limit = "12";
        this.limitnew = +this.limitnew + +this.limit;
        this.userService.getTestUsers(this.limitnew)
            .subscribe((usersnew) => {
                this.usersnew = usersnew
            }, (error) => {
                console.log('error', error);
            }, () => {
                this.done()
            });
    }

    done() {
        this.users = [...this.users, ...this.usersnew];
        console.log(this.users);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, subscription should be made only once. If you subscribe once, that function will be fired every time until the component destroyed. So please remove the subscription from LoadMore function.

First you have to import OnInit, OnDestroy lifcycle hooks from angular/core like below

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
```

After that inside component, make the subscription

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.userService.getTestUsers(this.limit).subscribe(  users => this.users = users);
  }
```

Don't forget to unsubscribe it when component destroyed.

```
ngOnDestroy(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: what is the alternative of subscription

Comment: No alternates for subscriptions..!